# Update column if received x otherwise update y

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

If I have a table with 3 columns: id,column1,column2. If i want to update column1 just when receiving "column1" parameter in URL request otherwise update column2 when receiving "column2" parameter in URL adress. Is that possible? I made that but i think that's not correct:

```
$sql= "UPDATE people SET 
answer_yes= '$answer_yes'+1,
answer_no='$answer_no'+1";
```

Thank you for helping.

EDIT: Now that is working (based on Richard Vivian answer)

```
    If($answer_yes==1)
{

    $sql= "UPDATE people SET answer_yes= answer_yes +1"or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else if ($answer_no==0)
    {
    $sql= "UPDATE people SET answer_no= answer_no+1" or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: @Curt: Flat model. just i have one table with no relations.

Comment: Sorry, I mean which RDBMS? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: @Curl: MySQL using wamp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 SQL statement options:

```
If($answer_yes)
{
$sql= "UPDATE people SET answer_yes= '$answer_yes'+1"
}
else
{
$sql= "UPDATE people SET answer_no= '$answer_no'+1"
}
```

Comment: That one seems pretty simple ;D. WIll try it now ;).

Comment: please see my edited post. I tried another idea. when i receive "1" in URL for answer_yes for example, the value of "answer_yes" in database will be incremented(that's what i want to do). Is that correct what i made, no error, but no incremention.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure which database model you are using, but the logic would be to pass a `NULL` value if you don't have a value to pass, and check that the values not null before updating.

**SQL Server**

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column1=ISNULL(@Column1,Column1),
    Column2=ISNULL(@Column2,Column2)
```

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column1=IFNULL($Column1,Column1),
    Column2=IFNULL($Column2,Column2)
```

What is happening here is that `ISNULL/IFNULL` is checking whether the first value passed to it is `NULL`, and if it is, its returning the 2nd value. The 2nd value is the same value as the current value, and therefore it updates it with the same value (ie. Not changing the value).

Comment: Curt please see my edited post. I tried another idea. when i receive "1" in URL for answer_yes for example, the value of "answer_yes" in database will be incremented(that's what i want to do). Is that correct what i made, no error, but no incremention.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE people 
SET answer_yes = COALESCE($answer_yes + 1, answer_yes),
    answer_no  = COALESCE($answer_no + 1, answer_no);
```

The [**`COALESCE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non `NULL`able value in the values passed to it. If any of the parameters `$answer_yes` or `$answer_no` were passed with a `NULL` value, then `$answer_yes + 1` and `$answer_no + 1` will be evaluated to `NULL` also, there for the `COALESCE` will return the column value, and in this case the column will be updated with its value, i.e, it won't changed.

Comment: `COALESCE`? `$answer_yes` is the parameter in URL adress and `answer_yes` is the column name in database?